# List Top 5 taxonomy terms based on number of post

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

One of my taxonomy is "team" and another one is "players". I am trying to list top 5 taxonomy based on a number of today's post. Please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: do you have custom taxonomies?

Comment: Yes, I do. Still couldn't get the code. Code provided by the dramatist below didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here I've written a SQL query based function for you. You can use it to also for getting the top taxonomy terms based on post date range. Here it is-

```
function the_dramatist_get_taxonomy_based_on_date_range_and_post_count( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $default_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'start_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'end_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('tomorrow')),
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $default_args );
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id AS terms, 
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}terms.name AS name,
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}terms.slug AS slug, 
                                   {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy AS taxonomy,
                                   COUNT({$wpdb->prefix}posts.id) AS posts
                            FROM   {$wpdb->prefix}posts 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}posts.id = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id ) 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 
                                                {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id ) 
                                   INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms 
                                           ON ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id = {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id ) 
                            WHERE  {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '%s'  
                                   AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_date BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
                            GROUP BY terms
                            ORDER BY posts DESC",
        array(
            $args['taxonomy'],
            $args['start_date'] . ' 00:00:00',
            $args['end_date'] . ' 00:00:00',
        )
    );
    return $wpdb->get_results($sql);
}
```

For you now usage you should use it like below-

```
$team_tax_terms = the_dramatist_get_taxonomy_based_on_date_range_and_post_count(array('taxonomy' => 'team'));


$players_tax_terms = the_dramatist_get_taxonomy_based_on_date_range_and_post_count(array('taxonomy' => 'players'));
```

Those `$team_tax_terms` and `$players_tax_terms` will give you the terms `term_id`, `slug`, `name` and `post_count`. And it will be ordered by `post_count` in descending order, that means the terms with most posts will appear in top. I think you should do a `print_r` before using this function. That will make the function return data structure clear to you.

> This method is tested. I tested it personally. Hope that helps you.

Comment: ps: the table prefix might not be `wp_`

Comment: I used this :
<?php 
$team_tax_terms = the_dramatist_get_taxonomy_based_on_date_range_and_post_count(array('taxonomy' => 'team')) ;
 print_r( $team_tax_terms );
?>
 
but got the output as below. 

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [terms] => 1674 [name] => Manchester United [slug] => manchester-united [taxonomy] => team [posts] => 10 )

Also, I use taxonomy image with shortcode:
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' ); 

Please give me edited code along with that shortcode.

Comment: Your saying is not clear to me. My function is giving you the categories id, name and slug. And I told you earlier. Now use that id, name or slug to get the category details. And I'm not sure what are you talking about shortcode. Please make it clear.

Comment: I'm actually very new to wordpress so I'm just trying to add taxonomy image of that term. so I'm using a plugin which gives taxonomy image output with print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' ); ..I need to get that taxonomy image just before taxonomy list. Also, please add that print_r in and give me a full code. Thanks @the_dramatist